# Ubuntu MATE freeze on logout/shutdown/reboot when running on Intel graphics card

Tags: nvidia, shutdown, intel-graphics, mate, hybrid-graphics

I have installed Ubuntu MATE 16.04 on a new Alienware 13 machine. My problem is that shutdown/reboot/logout stopped working properly and the system freezes one I try to do shutdown. The problem started after I tried to suspend the system and it lead to a freeze too. After extensive searching I found that this freeze on shutdown only happens when the system is switched to Intel card (it shuts down fine when Nvidia is on). Does anybody know the fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

I used to have the same problem with my [MSIGE62VR](https://us.msi.com/Laptop/GE62VR-Apache-Pro-6th-Gen-GTX-1060.html#hero-overview), the fix was to add:

`acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2009"`

in the kernel parameters.

Solution derived from [here](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/764#issuecomment-234494238)

Comment: Just pointing out that this also works with kaby lake CPUs and nvidia Pascal GPUs - in my case i5-7300hq + 1050Ti.