# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes with 4.10 kernel and Nouveau driver

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, kernel

I have the same freeze problem detailed here [Ubuntu 16.04 freezes with 4.10 kernel](https://askubuntu.com/q/939417/719386):

- Ubuntu version 16.04
- NVidia graphic card: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB
- Nouveau driver

Everything works fine with 4.8.0.58-generic kernel. I would like to continue to use Nouveau driver.

Today I tryied with 4.10.0-28-generic and I can login but if I try to logoff my notebook freeze. I tryied to logoff using menu (icon on top right) and "sudo poweroff" and the problem is the same.
My notebook freeze also if I press CRTL + ALT + F1 to open TTY.

Suggestions?

---

Update: 19 August

Same problem with 4.10.0-30-generic and 4.10.0-32-generic.

---

Update: 2 September

Same problem with 4.10.0-33-generic

---

Update: 21 September

Same problem with 4.10.0-35-generic

PS: I didn't try yet all the solutions suggested by [Karsus](https://askubuntu.com/users/498541/karsus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated to make answer more standalone:**

Your problem is likely related to ACPI.

Try editing `acpi_osi` kernel parameters according to the suggestions of this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872390/ubuntu-mate-freeze-on-logout-shutdown-reboot-when-running-on-intel-graphics-card/940495#940495).

Instructions on doing it temporarily (to test it) and permanently (if it fixes your problem) can he found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter/19487#19487):

**To temporarily add a boot parameter to a kernel:**

1. Start your system and wait for the GRUB menu to show (if you don't see a GRUB menu, press and hold the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key right after starting the system).
2. Now highlight the kernel you want to use, and press the <kbd>e</kbd> key. You should be able to see and edit the commands associated with the highlighted kernel.
3. Go down to the line starting with `linux` and add your temporary boot parameter `acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2009'"` to its end.
4. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to boot.

**To permanently add a boot parameter to a kernel:**

**Always test with a temporary change before making a permanent change.** I soft-bricked my laptop because I got overconfident with such changes.

Here is what one has to do to **permanently** edit boot parameters in order to fix ACPI:

The process to do so is described, for grub2, in more detail in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/19487/498541):

```
# open a terminal
$ gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
# Find the line starting with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and append foo=bar to its end. For example:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2009'"
# Save the file and close the editor.
# Finally, start a terminal and run:
$ sudo update-grub
```

To see the kernel parameters of a running kernel type:

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-33-generic root=UUID=221a0401-7879-4389-a6fe-fea2935f35e5 ro quiet splash acpi_osi=! "acpi_osi=Windows 2009" vt.handoff=7
```

Comment: I modified boot param for 4.10.0-33-generic but 1) I can open TTY but I can't write on it: no login and there is only the blick cursor 2) shutdown works. Solution is half-good because I need to use terminal. Thanks anyway

Comment: Have a check at this [bumblebee issue](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/764#issuecomment-309202205). There are several different suggestions. Maybe the modeset suggestion of that comment helps as well. Since you got a partial fix it looks like ACPI is part of your problem.

Comment: Using kernel 4.10.0-37-generic and kernel param `acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2009"` it works!